# How to close the phonegap inappbrowser when click on a button on a page that launched in inappbrowser?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

In my hybrid mobile application (developing for android and ios) I am launching sample.html page in inappbrowser using below code `window.open("sample.html","_blank","location=yes")`. With this it opens a inappbrowser window and loads sample.html page with url bar with 'X' mark in android and 'Done' button at the bottom in ios. If we click on 'X' mark in android or 'Done' button in ios it closes the inappbrowser. Now that I want to have the same behavior when I click on a button in sample.html. I have used window.close() but it is not working.

I am using IBM worklight framework for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InAppBrowser` is functionality that comes with Cordova.
You can read more about it, including all supported `event`s [in its documentation page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md).

There is no direct way to close an InAppBrowser instance "from within", so it needs to be worked-around.
Here's one way to achieve it:

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd1ckozxkl2cb2b/InAppBrowserProject.zip)

1. In your sample.html add some 'close' link like this, for example:

   ```
   <!-- Point to some non-existing end-point;
        We'll catch the error and use it to close the InAppBrowser. -->
   <a href="/close">Close</a>
   ```

   You can style the link to look like a button if you really want it to be a 'button'.
2. In your common\main.js in the Worklight app add the following, for example:

   ```
   var InAppBrowserReference;

   function wlCommonInit(){

   }

   function openInAppBrowser() {
       // Use location=no,toolbar=no in order to hide the supplied 'close' buttons
       // by the InAppBrowser instance.
       InAppBrowserReference = window.open('sample.html', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
       InAppBrowserReference.addEventListener('loaderror', closeInAppBrowser);
   }

   function closeInAppBrowser(event) {
       if (event.url.match("/close")) {
           InAppBrowserReference.close();
       }
   }
   ```

In the above code snippet, `openInAppBrowser()` is called from common\index.html in order to open the InAppBrowser for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I tried similar option already, but it didnot work for me. I think all the addeventlistners assigned to inappbrowser reference variable will work when that event executes from index.html but not from sample.html. In my case the loaderror event/function has to execute when a button/link is clicked on sample.html page. Please let me know if I am not understanding properly.

Comment: @user3878988, See the answer for a sample project.

Comment: Note that the application was built using the recently released Worklight Foundation 6.3 (now called MobileFirst Platform Foundation). So if you are using an older version of Worklight, just copy the code in index.html, sample.html and main.js to your own project.

Comment: When I copied the index.html,sample.html and main.js from your project it worked fine. But I am confused that I have also used same code in my project also, but it did not worked for me.Later after debugging and comparing my project and your sample project I found the issue. The issue is with jquery.mobile.js and jquery.js. If we include jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js and jquery.js libraries in our sample.html and run the application it is giving error loading the page issue when click on close button on sample.html page.Not sure what is conflicting.Please provide me any idea how to solve this.Thanks.

Comment: You can't just use jquery in that page, it's a different file altogether without any of the references to jquery. You'll need to look at the inappbrowser documentation regarding injecting CSS and js into a file opened in it. Note that inappbrowser is meant to open remote content, not local content. Maybe you shouldn't use that for your project and instead handle it differently.

Comment: In fact in my actual application I am launching the remote page which is hosted on some server in my inappbrowser. Just to check the feasibility of this functionality I am mocking that remote page and placing it in my local folder. The remote page is developed as a part of web/browser application. As I have to show the same remote page in my mobile application I am loading it in inappbrowser.

Comment: As said, you can't use the jQuery from the Worklight app in the InAppBrowser view unless you inject it via the InAppBrowser functionality for doing so (review the docs), but I think that you can now try this with the remote server code because it was already proven that you can close the page. Now you need to move forward and implement this in the real page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66700/discussion-between-user3878988-and-idan-adar).